# How to use opacity's theme tokens in Material Design 3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-you, material-design-3

During theme's migration process I stuck with opacity's token in Material Design 3. I didn't find any in [androidx.compose.material3](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary).

I'm looking for something like construction below I was used with Material Design 2

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (isSelected) ContentAlpha.high else ContentAlpha.medium)
```

Could you explain, how to control opacity with theme's tokens in Material Design 3? Thanks.